# php (codeigniter) passing view a model's data efficiently: array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm curious and maybe it's a pretty bad question. So I'm  just wondering where it's better to have an array with all the data elements or make all the elements into one element in array. 
So like:

```
$data1=array($var1=>$val1, $var2=>$var2);
or
$data2=array('data'=>$data1);
```

Then in view file, I will access the variables in the following 2 ways:
    $var1, $var2
    or 
    $data[$var1], $data[$var2]....

Is reading a bigger array more efficient or .... not really? Does it consume more memory?

So just to make it more clear, what I mean is by passing the info differently like above 2 ways, then I will read them either as variables or as elements in the big array. The answers so far seems to suggest that there's no real significant effects?

Comment: It doesn't really have a performance hit. Arrays are a major feature of PHP. The only time it would probably start affecting performance is when there are thousands of items.

Comment: CI extracts the variables passed to a view anyway, So you'll re-create the array as a local variable inside the view once you load it, so i doubt it has any real impact.

Comment: What do you mean with "efficient"?
You can only have one thing: high memory usage and high speed. Or low memory usage and low speed. Use an associative array to avoid sequential search through an array. PHP will take care of the speed by its internal mechanisms like caching.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays doesn't use much memory. 
In c++ compiler, 
it is a pointer for a place in memory which has division into byte blocks.It is ok to use an array as a parameter, rather than as many variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data1=array($var1=>$val1, $var2=>$var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//in controller
$data['var']=array('var1'=>$val1, 'var2'=>$var2);
$this->load->view('test',$data);

//in view  you can acess
<?php echo $var['var1'];?>
<?php echo $var['var2'];?>
```